# Ubuntu wont load, stuck for over an hour with "Started waiting until snapd is fully seeded"

Tags: boot, ram, snap

My Ubuntu installation was complaining that it was low on memory. So I moved some old school files from last semester off it, restarted and now it gets hung up on this every time I start. I just tried waiting as Google showed that it needed more time or entropy, so I tried random key presses and moving the mouse but nothing happened.

How do I get rid of this issue and boot my Ubuntu?

Comment: Sadly it was not.  I tried that already.

Comment: I've got the same issue but no lack of memory or disk space on my PC - I am trying to setup a dual boot, with windows shrunk to 250Gb leaving 250Gb for ubuntu. I can never get past the language choice screen, with no response to mouse clicks - and I've tried 3 different USB sticks at this point. This is on a razr blade.

Answer (score 5):

This was apparently caused by a lack of space on my PC, as I went into the system and deleted some files and it was able to load.  Turns out that there was around 65 GB of syslog.1 in the /var/log folder.  I don't know how it got there, but if you find yourself having this kind of error, check how much space you have on your PC.

Comment: /var/log/syslog and the other files in /var/log/ are log entries from the system, mainly reporting status and errors. A huge logfile indicates that something is/was wrong. If a log-file keeps growing, you should look into the file to see what the problem is, and find a solution for it. The files ending in .1 .2 and so on, is old logfiles, the current normally have no extensions.